# Why don't Bootstrap5 scroll areas work in customElements?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, web-component

I am trying to learn webcomponents and I'm trying to take a simple bootstrap example and turn it into some basic components.  A list component and an item component.

I am using the "List Group" example as my template:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/sidebars/

For some reason, all the other bootstrap styles work just fine (as long as I don't use the shadowDOM) but the scroll area will not work.  There are no errors in the console (the joy of web development), the list just cuts off at the end.

So the output of my static conent (which works) is IDENTICAL (compared it using notepad++) the only difference is that the HTML that makes up the component is wrapped in the cusomeElement tag that I made.

Here is an example you can copy paste into a text file, save as example.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>
    Target Reason Administration
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

html {
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100vh;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.bv-divider {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-width: 1px 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.bh-divider {
    height: 0.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-width: 1px 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.bi {
    vertical-align: -.125em;
    pointer-events: none;
    fill: currentColor;
}

.scrollarea {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="d-flex flex-nowrap">   
        <div class="align-items-stretch bg-white d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0" style="width: 380px;">
            <a class="align-items-center border-bottom d-flex flex-shrink-0 link-dark p-3 text-decoration-none" href="/">
                <span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Works without Component</span>
                <button class="btn" style="opacity: 0" type="button">Hidden for alignment</button>
            </a>
            <div id="contentArea" class="border-bottom list-group list-group-flush scrollarea overflow-auto">
                <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
                <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                    <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                        <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                            <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                    </a>
                </tbd-category>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bv-divider"></div>
        <cpr-category-list>
            <div class="align-items-stretch bg-white d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0" style="width: 380px;">
                <a class="align-items-center border-bottom d-flex flex-shrink-0 link-dark p-3 text-decoration-none" href="/">
                    <span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Dead when wrapped by component</span>
                    <button class="btn" style="opacity: 0" type="button">Hidden for alignment</button>
                </a>
                    <div id="contentArea" class="border-bottom list-group list-group-flush scrollarea ">
                        <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>
                    <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>    
                                        <div id="contentArea" class="border-bottom list-group list-group-flush scrollarea ">
                        <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>
                    <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>    

                    <div id="contentArea" class="border-bottom list-group list-group-flush scrollarea ">
                        <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>
                    <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>    

                    <div id="contentArea" class="border-bottom list-group list-group-flush scrollarea ">
                        <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>
                    <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>    

                    <div id="contentArea" class="border-bottom list-group list-group-flush scrollarea ">
                        <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>
                    <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>    

                    <div id="contentArea" class="border-bottom list-group list-group-flush scrollarea ">
                        <tbd-category name="ADVANCE" reasoncount="11" description="Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">ADVANCE</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">11</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Notify user when the event is X hours from a completion</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>
                    <tbd-category name="AXT_EXP" reasoncount="10" description="Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts">
                        <a class="lh-sm list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1" style="outline: none;" href="#">
                            <div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                                <strong class="mb-1">FTW_EXP</strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">10</small>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descr" class="col-12 mb-0 small">Category of codes to explain Expired Alerts</div>
                        </a>
                    </tbd-category>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </cpr-category-list>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just make sure your browser window is small enough to cut off some list items and you should see that the list on the left gets scroll bars while the list on the right (wrapped in a custom element) does not.

I have not included the component itself (it's proprietary) but the result is the same.

I have 2 questions:

1. why does some styling work inside the custom element and some does not?
2. how can I get the scrolling to work inside my component?

Thanks everyone for you time and attention.

Comment: Please search for answers; there is plenty written on shadowDOM and Bootstrap on StackOverflow

Comment: This is not a question about the shadowDOM and I have searched for answers to this already on stackoverflow, so unless you have a specific link you think solves my problem, then I don't see how this comment helps.

Comment: Does your CE have a shadowRoot?

Comment: No sir (well not anymore, it had one but bootsrap wouldn't work which I understand, so for now the whole component is in the liteDOM)

Comment: LightDOM is styled by global CSS, so the cause can not be the Custom Element. Then you have to question Bootstrap. Test if it works wrapped in an UnknownElement ``<foo-bar>``. Key is to test, and come up with a minimal _failing_ example. The code you post above is pointless, at least to me.  Create a Custom Element you can post. And use the [<>] button in the SO editor to create a running SO Snippet.

Comment: Danny, the example above is exactly what you are asking for.  In the context of the example, cpr-category-list is an UnknownElement and the entire file IS a minimal example and it is showing a failure... so perhaps try the example, THEN comment.